# Trying to increment using for nested loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to increment using for nested loops but not getting the desire result. The purpose for this is to check for diagonal matches for the game connect 4 using a 7x6 grid. Here is my code and results

```
    for i in range(6):
            for j in range(6):
                    print("[{}][{}]".format(i,j))
                    i+=1

    #This is the output i am trying to get. 
    [0][0]
    [1][1]
    [2][2]
    [3][3]
    [4][4]
    [5][5]
    [1][0]
    [2][1]
    [3][2]
    [4][3]
    [5][4]
    [2][0]
    [3][1]
    [4][2]
    [5][3]

    #But this is what i am getting
    [0][0]
    [1][1]
    [2][2]
    [3][3]
    [4][4]
    [5][5]
    [1][0]
    [2][1]
    [3][2]
    [4][3]
    [5][4]
    [6][5]
    [2][0]
    [3][1]
    [4][2]
    [5][3]
    [6][4]
    [7][5]
    [3][0]
    [4][1]
    [5][2]
    [6][3]
    [7][4]
    [8][5]
    [4][0]
    [5][1]
    [6][2]
    [7][3]
    [8][4]
    [9][5]
    [5][0]
    [6][1]
    [7][2]
    [8][3]
    [9][4]
    [10][5]
```

Comment: Modifying the loop variable has no effect when using `for` loops. You will have to use a while loop, or skip the iteration in a different way. Note that in the first `i` loop, `i` would be incremented 6 times within the `j` loop, so you would already exceed the range.

Comment: Also, why are you excluding the following from the desired results? `[3][0], [4][1], [5][2], [4][0], [5][1], [5][0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code returns your desired results without truncating the data.

```
for i in range(6):
   for j in range(6-i):
      print("[{}][{}]".format(i,j))
      i += 1
```

For your exact output:

```
for i in range(6):
   check = False
   for j in range(6-i):
      print("[{}][{}]".format(i,j))
      if i == 5 and j == 3:
         check = True
         break
      i += 1
   if check:
      break
```

Output:

```
[0][0]
[1][1]
[2][2]
[3][3]
[4][4]
[5][5]
[1][0]
[2][1]
[3][2]
[4][3]
[5][4]
[2][0]
[3][1]
[4][2]
[5][3]
```

Comment: Just ran that code but it didn't output what you indicated

Comment: Do you want it to stop at [5][3]? I updated the answer to truncate the data where you desired.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
N = 6
for start in range(N):
    for i, j in zip(range(start, N), range(N)):
        print("[{}][{}]".format(i,j))
```